# A request for a word similar to 'stumble in speech'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a rather formal **verb(phrase)** to mean **"involuntarily inserting a word from one's mother tongue in a speech made in one's foreign language because the person in question is in a very nerve-wrecking situation such as speaking in court"**

Example:

> A person whose second language is English, and first language is
>   French says the following:
>
> "I don't mean to blow things out proportion, but I think that what you
>   said is, uh, uh, 'injuste', uh, I mean, unfair!" (Heart pounding hard)

Note the involuntary insertion of the French word *injuste* into the English speech is involuntary because the person was **too nervous or self-conscious.** The insertion does not come from a lack a competency or command of lexicon, only nervousness.

I thought of *stumble* but I don't think it serves the purpose well.

Answer (score 2):

The formal term is **code-switching**, and the specific sub-category is **tag-switching** for switching words or phrases. It happens [involuntarily](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22involuntary%20code-switching%22&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&ei=cE64Yoe0EI2Dxc8PlOWs8AQ&ved=0ahUKEwiHrILXjMv4AhWNQfEDHZQyC04Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22involuntary%20code-switching%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ7QZYpA5gtg9oAXABeACAAd0BiAG1CJIBBTAuNS4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) also.

> Tag-switching is the switching of either a tag phrase or a word, or both, from one language to another, (common in intra-sentential switches). In Spanish-English switching one could say, "*Él es de México y así los criaron a ellos*, you know." ("*He's from Mexico, and they raise them like that*, you know.") 
> - *Code-switching*/*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)*

Comment: Thank you for the effort of researching, but code-switching is a choice that the speaker makes. It is never involuntary.

Comment: No, it can happen involuntarily, like a "reflex". You can search about "involuntary code-switching". There seems to be resources about psychological aspect of this.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of "reverting to one's mother tongue". http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/312196

Answer (score 0):

I would use *Momentary Lapse*.

Lapse on its own would also be appropriate but could imply that the speaker inserted a larger section of speech from their native language.